# Need some SQL suggestions for MS-Access Query based on the table examples

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm making a SQL to sort out of messy data table, TableA, based on the example below. I would much appreciate if you could show me some SQL suggestions to get a result like TableB.

The sample tables I put below are a simplified example to clarify what I want to get. I have just tried like:

```
 SELECT F1, Sum(F3) FROM TableA GROUP BY F1
```

But I don't know how to nest the data on F2 based on F1 grouping.

enter image description here

My expected result is just like TableB using one-liner SQL.

Comment: *Edit your question* if you need to add information.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how to add some table examples here. I have an image of table if I could put it here.

Comment: Click the "edit" link, paste in your table text, select it and click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Thanks for your solution and sorry for the late reply scaisEdge, that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data  sample

```
     [TableA] 
     F1     F2      F3 
     003    Pt01    430 
     003    Pt02    220 
     003    Pt03    230 
     003    Pt04    110 
     001    Pt01    300 
     001    Pt02    250 
     001    Pt03    120 
     001    Pt04    450 
     002    Pt01    400 
     002    Pt02    230 
     002    Pt03    130 
     001    Pt02    340 
     001    Pt03    150 
     002    Pt01    200 
     002    Pt03    560 
     003    Pt02    400 
     003    Pt03    540 
     003    Pt04    340 
     003    Pt05    200
```

and you want the result

```
     [TableB] 
     F4     F5      F6 
     001    Pt01    300 
            Pt02    590 
            Pt03    270 
            Pt04    450 
     002    Pt01    600 
            Pt02    230 
            Pt03    690 
     003    Pt01    430 
            Pt02    620 
            Pt03    770 
            Pt04    450 
            Pt05    200 


    select  f1 as f4, f2 as f5, sum(f3) as f6 
    from tableA 
    group by  f1, f2
```

this query produce repeated value for F4 or hide the repeated  valud you should work at presentation level